# How do I properly extract/convert JSON data into objects?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have structure below coming via webhook and I'm having trouble understanding if there is built in action in Logic App to get nicely formatted object array of `rows` which is inside table, where each item will have name and associated value with it.

```
  "SearchResults": {
                    "tables": [
                        {
                            "name": "PrimaryResult",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "name": "TimeGenerated",
                                    "type": "datetime"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "ResourceGroup",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "ActivityStatusValue",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "d_resource",
                                    "type": "dynamic"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "c_title",
                                    "type": "dynamic"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "c_details",
                                    "type": "dynamic"
                                }
                            ],
                            "rows": [
                                [
                                    "2020-06-18T16:30:07.89Z",
                                    "USEASTPROD",
                                    "Updated",
                                    "aueglbwvhypap07",
                                    "Remote disk disconnected",
                                    "We're sorry, your virtual machine is unavailable because of connectivity loss to the remote disk. An unexpected problem is preventing us from automatically recovering your virtual machine."
                                ],
                                [
                                    "2020-06-18T16:30:07.89Z",
                                    "USEASTPROD",
                                    "Updated1",
                                    "agggggypap07",
                                    "Remote disk disconnected",
                                    "We're sorry, your virtual machine is unavailable because of connectivity loss to the remote disk. An unexpected problem is preventing us from automatically recovering your virtual machine."
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
}
```

I'd like it to be an array where columns are entity name and each value from `rows` is it's value like below

```
"rows": [
                                [
                                    "timeGenerated" :"2020-06-18T16:30:07.89Z",
                                    "ResourceGroup": "USEASTPROD",
                                    "ActivityStatusValue":"Updated",
                                    "d_resource" : "aueglbwvhypap07",
                                    "c_title" : "Remote disk disconnected",
                                    "c_details": "We're sorry, your virtual machine is unavailable because of connectivity loss to the remote disk. An unexpected problem is preventing us from automatically recovering your virtual machine."
                                ],
                                [
                                    "timeGenerated" :"2020-06-18T16:30:07.89Z",
                                    "ResourceGroup": "USEASTPROD",
                                    "ActivityStatusValue":"Updated1",
                                    "d_resource" : "agggggypap07",
                                    "c_title" : "Remote disk disconnected",
                                    "c_details": "We're sorry, your virtual machine is unavailable because of connectivity loss to the remote disk. An unexpected problem is preventing us from automatically recovering your virtual machine."
                                ]
                            ]
```

Comment: Could you please provide a data(rows) sample of which you expect ?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: The sample you provided shows each item in rows still be surrounded by `[` and `]`, do you want each item as array ? Or use `{` and `}` (as object) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this requirement, we can just use liquid with integration account in logic app to implement it. Please refer to the steps below:

**1.** We need to create an integration account on azure portal first and link it to your logic app. You can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account).

**2.** In my logic app, I initialize a variable and store your data(add a `{}` around the data) to simulate your situation.

[image]

**3.** Then use "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action to parse the string above.
[image]

**4.** Create a liquid map in local (I named it as `testRow.liquid`) with the code below:

```
{% assign rows = content.SearchResults.tables[0].rows %}

{
    "rows": [
        {% for item in rows %}
            {
                "timeGenerated": "{{item[0]}}",
                "ResourceGroup": "{{item[1]}}",
                "ActivityStatusValue": "{{item[2]}}",
                "d_resource": "{{item[3]}}",
                "c_title": "{{item[4]}}",
                "c_details": "{{item[5]}}"
            },
        {% endfor %}
    ]
}
```

Upload the liquid map(testRow.liquid) to your integration account, for this step you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform#create-liquid-template-or-map-for-your-integration-account).

**5.** Then use "Transform JSON to JSON" action", choose the `Body` from "Parse JSON" action above and use the map which you upload.
[image]

**6.** After running the logic app, we can get the result as below:
[image]

The whole result json is:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "timeGenerated": "6/18/2020 4:30:07 PM",
      "ResourceGroup": "USEASTPROD",
      "ActivityStatusValue": "Updated",
      "d_resource": "aueglbwvhypap07",
      "c_title": "Remote disk disconnected",
      "c_details": "We're sorry, your virtual machine is unavailable because of connectivity loss to the remote disk. An unexpected problem is preventing us from automatically recovering your virtual machine."
    },
    {
      "timeGenerated": "6/18/2020 4:30:07 PM",
      "ResourceGroup": "USEASTPROD",
      "ActivityStatusValue": "Updated1",
      "d_resource": "agggggypap07",
      "c_title": "Remote disk disconnected",
      "c_details": "We're sorry, your virtual machine is unavailable because of connectivity loss to the remote disk. An unexpected problem is preventing us from automatically recovering your virtual machine."
    }
  ]
}
```

**By the way:**

1. The format of the sample you provided is invalid in json, we must use `{}` instead of `[]` in each of the item.
2. In liquid map, it will convert your datetime to another format automatically.

Hope it helps~